# Posting with privacy setting through Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on Facebook with custom privacy setting:

```
$postRequest=new FacebookRequest($sess,'POST','/me/feed',array(
  'message'=>'My first post using graph api ',
  'description'=>'new Description',
  'privacy'=>array('description'=>'Only Me','value'=>'SELF'),
  'link' => 'www.example.com'
)
```

but an error occurs:

> (#100) privacy must contain a valid privacy 'value'

What's wrong?

Comment: but how the syntax will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You must encode your PHP array into a JSON array:

```
'privacy' => json_encode(array('description'=>'Only Me','value'=>'SELF')),
```